# Remove space between cell and header

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've create a uitableview with two sections. However there seems to be some unwanted space between the second section header and the last cell in the first section (see screenshot). Does anybody know how to remove it?[image]

Code per request:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionHeader") as MyRentalsScetionsHeaders

    switch(section){
    case 0:
        headerCell.sectionName.text = "Upcoming"
        headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 87/255.0, green: 189/255.0, blue: 135/255.0, alpha: 1)

    default:
        headerCell.sectionName.text = "Ended"
        headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 203/255.0, green: 205/255.0, blue: 200/255.0, alpha: 1)
    }

    return headerCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    switch(section){
    case 0:
        return 45.0
    default:
        return 30.0
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.00001
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

### Edit

My current solution is setting the height for the footer to 0.00001, which is allowed. It's not really the most ideal solution, but it looks a lot better :) if anybody know a pixel-perfect solution, I'd love that!

Comment: Post your heightForHeader/heightForFooter and viewForHeader/viewForFooter methods.

Comment: I think label has less height than 30( height for second header). Try to return height of it header.

Answer (score 2):

Select TableView > Open Size Inspector > Set SectionHeight of Header to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Select tableview and in attribute inspector. There is option to set space between header and footer. 22 is default.

Comment: I'm able to set to space to 1, but why can't I set it to 0?